# Using AJAX Call Response Status Text Returns Empty with HTTPS URL?

Tags: ajax, httpresponse, http-status-codes

AJAX Call Response Status Text Returns Empty with HTTPS URL

I hosted my .NET web application using an HTTPS URI. I experienced an issue where the AJAX response status text returned as empty, which is the cause of the issue. There is a check, (xmlhttp.statusText == "OK"), but we are receiving a NULL value in this case.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xIu9.png)

When I use the HTTP URL, I am able to retrieve the statustext value correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr3SB.png)

But, I using the HTTPS URL, I get an empty value for the statustext.

When I use an HTTPS URL, I receive a status text value of "OK".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.